# what is the means of "f" in this def function?

Tags: python, function, class

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}({self.age})"
```

I don't understand it, What is the means of "f" in this return function

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

It is called an format string.
Briefly - Formatted strings are to address some of the shortcomings other methods for formatting strings had

some differences between f.string and format()